# giving a unique element

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 &-1 &0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 &1 &-1 \end{bmatrix}$

B) Given $\boldsymbol{b} \in \mathbb{R}^2 $, give the unique element $\boldsymbol{x} \in \boldsymbol{R}(A)$ so that $A\boldsymbol {x}=\boldsymbol  {b} $[my work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqsfJ.jpg)

This is what I thought you should do, but I don't believe this gives me a unique  element does it? since x could be a thing right or am I misunderstanding the problem? Could someone please explain.

Comment: Is $R(A)$ the rowspace of $A$?

Comment: Yes R(A) means rowspace of A.

Comment: In general there is no **unique** such $\;\vec x\;$ , but many...see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that

$$A\vec v=\begin{pmatrix}1&\!-1&0&0\\0&0&1&\!-1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\\w\end{pmatrix}=\binom{x-y}{z-w}$$

and then there is **no unique** $\;\vec v\;$ in general.... For example, for $\;\binom00\;$ , you have infinite options:

$$A\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}=A\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}=A\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}=A\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\3\\3\end{pmatrix}=\ldots=\binom00$$

Answer (score 0):

In general, there is not a unique $\mathbf x\in\Bbb R^4$ which solves this system for any $\mathbf b\in\Bbb R^2$. However, we want to find $\mathbf x\in R(A)$, which is more confined. Immediately from the matrix $A$ (since it is already in reduced row echelon form) we see that the rowspace of $A$ is given as $R(A)=Span\left([1,-1,0,0],[0,0,1,-1]\right)$. So we want to find $\mathbf x$ which is a linear combination of those spanning vectors. As you already showed, the solution to $A\mathbf x=\mathbf b$ has the form $\mathbf x=[x_2,x_2,x_4,x_4]$, where $x_2,x_4\in\Bbb R$ are the free variables. So now we want to solve the system:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\-1&0\\0&1\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}\mathbf c=\begin{bmatrix}x_2\\x_2\\x_4\\x_4\end{bmatrix}$$
to find the $\mathbf x$ which is a linear combination of the row vectors of $A$ (where $\mathbf c\in\Bbb R^2$ is some coefficient vector). From this you should be able to find the unique values of $x_2,x_4$ such that the above system is consistent (which means that $\mathbf x$ is in the rowspace of $A$).

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly then, $x_2=(1,0)$ and $x_4=(0,1)$ and I would write my answer as Row(A)=span{(1,0),(0,1)}?

Comment: @user6259845 No. $x_2$ and $x_4$ are numbers, not vectors. What I suggest you do is row reduce this system: $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&|&x_2\\-1&0&|&x_2\\0&1&|&x_4\\0&-1&|&x_4\end{bmatrix}$$ and determine which values of $x_2,x_4$ give a consistent system. These values for the parameters will give you the unique $\mathbf x$ which is in $R(A)$. Note that this is only for $A\mathbf x=\mathbf 0$ since in your solution you solved the homogeneous system. You must find $\mathbf x$ which solves the system for any $\mathbf b$.